# Index fragmentation

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a Azure SQL database with most tables fragmented more than 95%. I am rebuilding the indexes weekly. Tables are truncated and inserted on each load (Every 2 hours). After rebuilding, fragmentation increases rapidly and reaches 95% in couple of days. How can I improve the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Use *DROP and Re-Create index* method to reduce Fragmentation in Index.

•   Reducing Fragmentation in Index: if `avg_fragmentation_in_percent` between 30% to 100% then use **ALTER INDEX REBUILD:** This is replacement for DBCC DBREINDEX to rebuild the index online or offline. also use the drop and re-create index method.

Refer - [SQL Server - Fragmentation on azure SQL database](https://blog.ithubcity.com/details/sql-server/sql-server/8/240/sql-server--fragmentation-on-azure-sql-database)

Comment: Right. After rebuilding the index, fragmentation drops down below 1%. Again, in couple of days, it increases to more than 95%. What could be the reason for that?